# I am not able to getSelection() in useVueQuill

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-quill-editor

I am trying to get the cursor coordinates to be able to add some text but when i am trying to use getSelection i got this error : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getSelection')

```
  <QuillEditor ref="quill" :options="editorOption" v-model:content="payload.body" contentType="html" />

<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { QuillEditor } from '@vueup/vue-quill';
  import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css';

  const props = defineProps({
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    id: {
      type: Number
    }
  });
  const emit = defineEmits(['update:payload', 'loading'])
  const currentRoute = useRoute();

  const quill = ref(null)
  console.log(quill.value);
  
  const selection = quill.value.getSelection();
```

Comment: The error means `quill.value` is null at the time you try to call `getSelection()`. Vue components have [lifecycles](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram) you should familiarize yourself with. You call this function as soon as the component is created, but not yet mounted. `<QuillEditor>` having not yet been rendered is still null.  Of course trying to call a function on null will lead to an error. Why are you trying to call `getSelection` as soon as it's created anyways? There won't be a selection to get. Try using it inside a function that you call when needed

Comment: @yoduh thank you, this was stupid mistake, but now i get "quill.value.getSelection is not a function"

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with Quill Editor.  I would guess from the [documentation](https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/api/methods.html#getquill) you actually need to call `getQuill()` first?  e.g. `quill.value.getQuill().getSelection()`